# Custom message not being sent when OOO (Service) used in Lotus Notes 9.0.0

Tags: lotus-notes, out-of-office

We have several users who cannot get a custom message to be sent out using the Out of Office Service in Lotus 9.0.0. All the recipient receives are the auto part of the message. Strange. Anyone know anything about this, or how to even troubleshoot.

========================================================================
We figured this out. We had used the Admin Tool to remove OOO profiles, but that didn't seem to work. We discovered that we had to restart the router on the mail server for these fixes to take effect.

Comment: The ooo-message is correctly set in the preferences ?

Comment: Yes, we checked these. I have posted the solution above.

Answer (score 1):

We figured this out. We had used the Admin Tool to remove OOO profiles, but that didn't seem to work. We discovered that we had to restart the router on the mail server for these fixes to take effect.